# Javascript Animate Toggle for 3 forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

At the moment I have 2 forms. Login form and Registration form.
I use Javascript Toggle to switch between them. But now I want to add a 3th form. How can I do this? So I want to be able to switch from Login form to Register form OR to Forgot Password form and from those 2 back to Login form.

Here you see how I did it now in my View:

(The only thing in my partial views is a form with a `a` tag at the bottom to activate .js code)

```
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <!--Login Form-->
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_LoginView"); }

        <!--Register Form-->
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_RegisterView"); }

    </div>
</div>
```

And my .js file:

```
//Toggle between login and registration form
$('.switch a').click(function () {
$('form').animate({ height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle" }, "slow");
});
```

And the .css code:

```
.register-form {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information I could get from your question, I think your intentions are to animate the switching between multiple forms. This will hover require a little more logic written in your JavaScript.

Based on the switch mechanism already used by you I came up with this solution:

```js
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
  var selector = $(this).data("toggle");
  if ($(selector).css('display') != 'block') {
    $('form').hide();
  }
  $(selector).animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
```

```css
.switch a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: grey;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.form1 {
  background: red;
}

.form2 {
  background: blue;
}

.form3 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"    
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="switch">
    <a data-toggle=".form1">Form1</a>
    <a data-toggle=".form2">Form2</a>
    <a data-toggle=".form3">Form3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <form class="form1"></form>
    <form class="form2"></form>
    <form class="form3"></form>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is an efficient and easy to implement way.
You can check the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g27rs149/92/)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to toggle between more elements is that way:

The active element has a acive-class (is-active) all other element are hidden with css.

When someone click on "show form 1" then remove all active-classes and add it only to the form-1.

To animate it use css transitions.

```js
function hideAllForms() {
  $('.form').removeClass('is-active');
}

$('.js-show-form').on('click', (event) => {
    const $el = $(event.currentTarget);
    
   hideAllForms();
   
   $('#form-' + $el.data('form')).addClass('is-active');
});
```

```css
.form { display:none; background-color: red; }
.form.is-active { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <form id="form-1" class="form is-active">form1</form>
   <form id="form-2" class="form" >form2</form>
   <form id="form-3" class="form" >form3</form>
</div>

<a class="js-show-form" data-form="1">show form 1</a><br />
<a class="js-show-form" data-form="2">show form 2</a><br />
<a class="js-show-form" data-form="3">show form 3</a><br />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple code:

```
$(function(){

    $('form').hide();
    $('form').first().show();
    //Toggle between login and registration form
    $('a.switch').on('click', function () {

        var visibleForm = $('form:visible');

        $(visibleForm).hide();

        if($(visibleForm).next().length > 0)
        {            
            $(visibleForm).next().animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
        }
        else
        {
            $(visibleForm).siblings('form:first').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
        }

    });
});
```

and this is the HTML:

```
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <!--Login Form-->
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_LoginView"); }

        <!--Register Form-->
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_RegisterView"); }


        <!--Another Form-->
        ...
        <!--Another Form-->
        ...
        <!--Another Form-->
        ...
        <!--Another Form-->
        ...
        <!--Another Form-->
        ...
        <!--Another Form-->
        ...

    </div>
</div>
<a href='#' class='switch'>Switch</a>
```

Comment: yes you can add as many forms as you can, and the Switch link will still rotate between them